# Render gets too dark after clicking "Animation" button

Tags: rendering, animation, lighting

During the rendering process of a short animation, I have come across
a problem with too dark PNG images being rendered out.

It seems that everything looks fine within Blender - once I click F12,
everything is lit the way it should be, however after clicking "Animation"
the entire scene is way too dark.

Could you please help me with this? Any ideas what I do wrong? :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats kinda strange, if you do a still render ( F12) the result should be the same as for animation render (CTRL+F12). Especially since you render to bitmaps (which is recommended as it protects you against crashes of blender, later use video editing to import the image strip and render to mp4 (or use virtualdub for that)

It might be though that you made a node setup in compositor, that somehow darkens it, because things there happen after a render result.

Comment: Post your colour management settings, as well as codec details.